# ".send is not a function", trying to let player 1 know that player 2 connected. (NodeJS, websockets, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

So I have been trying to get this to work all day now. 
I am creating a simple 2-player web based game using JS and NodeJS, I want to use websockets with this project.

I have gotten so far to let both players connect to the socket, player one will wait for the second player to connect.

When player 2 connects, there is a message sent to Player 2's client, saying that he can start, at which he sends a message back in which he says that he is starting, hence the 'message == "Started"'.

Then when the message has arrived from player 2 at the server, I would like the server to send a message to player 1, the only problem is that "game.playerOne.send" doesn't work, the log says that it's not a function.

To be clear: 
Because game.addPlayer(con.id) was executed, game.playerOne contains the connection ID of player one.

This is the code I'm talking about:

```
const wss = new websocket.Server({ server });
var websockets = {};

var game = new Game(gameStats.started++);
var connectionID = 0;

wss.on("connection", function(ws) {

    let con = ws;
    con.id = connectionID++;
    console.log(con.id + " has connected");
    let player = game.addPlayer(con.id);
    websockets[con.id] = game;

    console.log("Player %s placed in game %s", ws.id, game.id);

    if (game.twoConnected()) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            ws.send("Player 1 is ready!");
        }, 1000);
        game = new Game(gameStats.started++);
    }

    con.on("message", function incoming(message) {
        let game = websockets[con.id];

        let isPlayerOne = (game.playerOne === con);

        if (isPlayerOne) {

        } else {
            if (message == "Started") {
                game.playerOne.send(message);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I would really like to know how I would go about sending a message to the other websocket (Player 1's socket) and why "game.playerOne.send" is not a valid function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I highly recommend using Socket.IO. It will just make things so much easier for you. https://socket.io/

Comment: @Arjan I forgot to add, I //have// to use the websocket stuff and am not allowed to use anything else (school project). Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: You are adding ID's of the websocket objects to your player array, not the websocket itself. Therefore you are calling 'send' on an integer, not a websocket object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are adding ID's of the websocket objects to your player array, not the websocket itself. Therefore you are calling 'send' on an integer, not a websocket object.

*Quoted from my comment.*

---

I wasn't able to test this but I changed the line suffixed by `// <--`. If this is not the solution you are after, I suggest that you edit your question to contain the functions responsible for storing and retrieving the player and all the games so we can take a better look at how and what objects are being stored.

On a sidenote, I suggest using `console.log` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)) on, for example, your `game.playerOne`. This way you can see all of the properties of the object in your debugging console.

```
const wss = new websocket.Server({ server });
var websockets = {};

var game = new Game(gameStats.started++);
var connectionID = 0;

wss.on("connection", function(ws) {
    let con = ws;
    con.id = connectionID++;
    console.log(con.id + " has connected");
    let player = game.addPlayer(con); // <-- this
    websockets[con.id] = game;

    console.log("Player %s placed in game %s", ws.id, game.id);

    if (game.twoConnected()) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            ws.send("Player 1 is ready!");
        }, 1000);
        game = new Game(gameStats.started++);
    }

    con.on("message", function incoming(message) {
        let game = websockets[con.id];

        let isPlayerOne = (game.playerOne === con);

        if (isPlayerOne) {

        } else {
            if (message == "Started") {
                game.playerOne.send(message);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wooh, alright! Thanks so much for this! It works like a charm now :)
Feel kinda stupid for having not seen that...